# Exception in Masstransit Saga Class which is connected to Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, masstransit, saga

Below is the error i am getting on my saga class which is "MassTransitStateMachine". I am not sure why it is giving this error as it is working when i switch to in memory saga repository. Error: MassTransit.Messages Warning: 0 : R-RETRY rabbitmq://localhost/IMembersLoginSaga 7c2d0000-8af1-d8cb-0f3a-08d6e7b9f5b1 Element '_id' does not match any field or property of class ct.members.domain.Models.MemberLoginStateInstance., System.FormatException: Element '_id' does not match any field or property of class ct.members.domain.Models.MemberLoginStateInstance.MassTransit.Messages Error: 0 : R-FAULT rabbitmq://localhost/IMembersLoginSaga 7c2d0000-8af1-d8cb-0f3a-08d6e7b9f5b1 ct.component.abstraction.Consumer.Members.IMemberLoginResponse ct.members.domain.Models.MemberLoginStateInstance(00:00:00.0045448) Element '_id' does not match any field or property of class ct.members.domain.Models.MemberLoginStateInstance., System.FormatException: Element '_id' does not match any field or property of class ct.members.domain.Models.MemberLoginStateInstance.

InstanceState(s => s.CurrentState);

```
                        Event(() => Create, x => 
                            x.CorrelateById(ml => ml.CorrelationId, context => context.Message.CorrelationId));

                        Event(() => Response, x => x.CorrelateById(context => context.Message.CorrelationId));

                        Initially(
                            When(Create)
                                .Then(context =>
                                {
                                    context.Instance.CorrelationId = context.Data.CorrelationId;
                                    context.Instance.EmailAddress = context.Data.EmailAddress;
                                    context.Instance.Password = context.Data.Password;
                                    context.Instance.Created = DateTime.Now;
                                })
                                .ThenAsync(context => Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"member email is {context.Instance.EmailAddress}"))
                                .Publish(context => new MemberloginPublish(context.Instance))
                                .TransitionTo(Approve)
                            );

                        During(Approve,
                            When(Response)
                                .Then(context =>
                                {
                                    context.Instance.CorrelationId = context.Data.CorrelationId;
                                    context.Instance.Token = context.Data.Token;
                                })
                                .ThenAsync(context => Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Token: {context.Data.Token} received"))
                                .Finalize());

                        SetCompletedWhenFinalized();


             private Event<IMembersLoginSaga> Create { get; set; }
             private Event<IMemberLoginResponse> Response { get; set; }
             private State Approve { get; set; }


            Startup class

            opt.AddBus(context => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
                            {
                                var host = cfg.Host(new Uri(MasstransitSettings["Server"]), hostConfigurator =>
                                {
                                    hostConfigurator.Username(MasstransitSettings["UserName"]);
                                    hostConfigurator.Password(MasstransitSettings["Password"]);
                                });

                                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, nameof(IMembersLoginSaga), ep =>
                                {

                                    ep.PrefetchCount = 16;
                                    ep.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Interval(2, 100));
                                    ep.ConfigureConsumers(context);

                                    ep.StateMachineSaga(new MemberLoginStateMachine(),
                                        new MongoDbSagaRepository<MemberLoginStateInstance>(dbconnection,new MongoDbSagaConsumeContextFactory())
                                        //new InMemorySagaRepository<MemberLoginStateInstance>()
                                        );
                                });


                            }));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decorate a mongoDB attribute which is BsonId() on correlationId in saga machine state instance class. This will fix the issue